# Get value from DOM at run time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a value from a textbox and I'm only returning `[object Object]`.

```
var key = $('body').on('click', '#ReportReferenceElectrical',function() {
    $('#ReportReferenceElectrical').val();
});
var REPORTS_KEY = key;
```

I have tried the usual:

```
var key = $('#ReportReferenceElectrical').val();
```

The `JS` is in an `iife` and the value needs to retrieved when I submit the form to save but using this way its empty as the value was empty when the form loaded, I though the top code snippet might return me the value, but not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback will get executed only when it is triggered. In this case, manually  `$.fn.trigger`ing isn't an option, I suppose as it will be `""`(Empty)

What you need is a callback.

```
function callback(key) {
   alert(key);
   // do something with the key now
}
```

And then call it in the event handler. I'd suggest going for the `blur` event rather than `click`

```
$('body').on('blur', '#ReportReferenceElectrical',function() {
    callback($('#ReportReferenceElectrical').val());
});
```

Comment: What do I put in the callback?

Comment: @StudentRik put all the code which utilizes the key inside the callback.

Comment: I only want the value of the textbox, do I just put that? what is the key I'm passing, I don't get it

Comment: @StudentRik check my edit and try out to know what's going on. Click on the element and then you should see a alert

Comment: it fires as soon as i enter the box and the alert is empty, can i stop it from firing until it is complete

Comment: @StudentRik check my edit. Now after the textbox loses its focus, you'll get an alert.